# How do I browse pictures and files on an android phone via USB?

Tags: usb, files, android

I've got an android LG P690 mobile phone.
I would like to know how to browse its pictures,
videos, and music files from my Ubuntu Desktop system.

I've figured out how to do this with Blutooth, but would
also like to do this using the physical USB to micro USB B
connector between the PC and the mobile phone.

Do I need to install any special drivers in order to get
this to work?

Comment: In my phone(GSmart with Android 2.2) I do next: connect phone and in menu choose Data Storage. Than go to Notification menu and choose Copy files from sd card, press Turn on sd card.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to install any drivers for USB drives on newer versions of ubuntu, it's like inserting a USB storage drive.

I didn't use a L.G android phone, but this should work on all android phones. Don't know if L.G has tweaked these settings.

This is how I do it on my moto droid.
After you connect your droid via USB go to Settings->USB connection and choose mass storage (MSC).

Run "lsusb" in a terminal and check if your phone is already identified, but drive is not mounted.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to install any drivers for USB drives (I own a LG P692, which has exactly the HW of yours plus the NFC transceiver).

Just follow these steps:

1. Make sure MSC is active in your Android phone (`Settings -> USB connection-> Mass storage (MSC)` shall be checked);
2. Connect PC and phone with the USB cable;
3. A popup should appear in your phone. Tap the `Activate Mass Storage` button (or similar, I am not sure about the string in English language) and wait a little while;

When the spinning icon in the tapped button is gone, you should be able to browse SD-Card content in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely try [AirDroid](http://web.airdroid.com/).

1. Install Airdroid on your phone through Market
2. In a PC with an internet connection, go to http://web.airdroid.com/, just follow the instructions there

Comment: So I must necessarily install something on my phone to get this to work. Then how come during development with eclipse one does not need this kind of stuff to install apk s?

Comment: Also, on windows this is not necessary, so why would it be necessary on linux?

Comment: I told you one way to do what you want. Off course there's others.